# Improve Accuracy on Protein Sequence SNP Classification Using CNNs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to classify protein sequence single nucleotide polymorphisms (SNPs) using convolutional neural networks (CNNs). My dataset consists of Wavelet Coherence Transform scalograms representing these SNP sequences. However, despite trying various CNN architectures and utilizing transfer learning techniques, I've been unable to achieve an accuracy greater than 62% on both the training and validation sets.[some images from the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZtka.png)

How dealing with datasets where images are highly similar ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please note that improving a machine learning model is not a programming question.